# Qt GUI application on macOS: how to find the currently active screen?

Tags: c++, qt

We are developing a macOS application whose GUI is relying on Qt.

At startup, we want to `show()` the `QMainWindow` at a specific location on the currently active screen (with multi screen systems in mind).

Is there a way to get the `QScreen` representing the currently active screen?

From our test, `QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()` is the first screen (which is consistent with the name), but we cannot find an equivalent for the active screen.

Answer (score 1):

Qt5 provides functionality to do so, the [`QWindow::setScreen`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#setScreen) method sets the screen on which the window should be shown.

Any widget provides access to this pointer via `QWidget::windowHandle()`:

```
QWidget * widget = new QWidget();
auto screens = qApp->screens();
// compute the index
widget->windowHandle()->setScreen(screens[index]);
widget->showFullScreen();
```

To get the screen number, you can use the mouse position and assume that the screen with the mouse is the one with the current focus:

```
QPoint globalCursorPos = QCursor::pos();
int mouseScreen = qApp->desktop()->screenNumber(globalCursorPos);
```

So the final code can be something like that:

```
QWidget * widget = new QWidget();
const auto globalCursorPos = QCursor::pos();
const auto mouseScreen = qApp->desktop()->screenNumber(globalCursorPos); 
widget->windowHandle()->setScreen(qApp->screens()[mouseScreen]);
widget->showFullScreen();
```

### Windows

If this approach does not fit your needs, you will need to perform some OS calls.

For instance, on Windows, you can use [`MonitorFromWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromwindow):

```
HMONITOR active_monitor_number = MonitorFromWindow(GetActiveWindow(), MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
```

If you need more information about the screen, you can use Qt or  [`GetMonitorInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmonitorinfoa).

I am not a Mac OS X developer, but it may exist a similar API

Comment: Sadly this is not correct: the mouse cursor can be on an inactive screen (which remains inactive until the mouse is clicked on its geometry)

Comment: You are right,  I did manage to get the current monitor on Windows, I added the code. You may use something similar on MAC OS. I can't find a way to do it via the Qt API.

Answer (score 1):

I did it in the following way:

```
#if (QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 10, 0))
    QPoint topLeft = QPoint(0, 0);
    QScreen* currentScreen = QGuiApplication::screenAt(QCursor::pos());
    if (nullptr != currentScreen) {
        topLeft = currentScreen->geometry().topLeft();
    }
#else
    QPoint topLeft =
      qApp->desktop()
        ->screenGeometry(qApp->desktop()->screenNumber(QCursor::pos()))
        .topLeft();
#endif
    someWidget->move(mapFromGlobal(topLeft) + QPoint(offset, offset));
```

Note that, sometimes, you may get `nullptr` for `currentScreen` (in my case if primary screen is at the bottom and mouse pos at the bottom or left edge on the primary screen).